# why I got error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Tags: java, arrays

Create an int array named a with 1000 elements, and give the first element the value 1, the second element the value 2, and so on.

```
int[ ] a = new int[1000];
  for (int i = 0; i <= a.length; i = i + 1){
    a[i] = i;
  }
```

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: The code you have posted does not result in an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Um what if: "try { a[i] = i; } catch ( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex1 ) { System.out.println("It was at index: " + i); }" ?

Comment: In your edited code, the loop terminator should be "i < a.length", not "<=".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your edit is what the code actually was it's just because this check:

```
i <= a.length
```

This is not good because array indexes in Java run from `0` to `length - 1`. This means if your array length is `1000`, the last index is `999`.

So it should be the way it was before the edit:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i = i + 1) {
```

Comment: how do i got a[1000]? if the code is in this way i < a.length + 1, the error still exists.

Comment: There is no a[1000]. That is the ***index*** of the ***1,001-st*** element, which does not exist. The first element in any array has an index of 0.

Comment: `i < a.length + 1` is the same as `i <= a.length`. The way the code was [when you first posted the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22187741/revisions) was the right way to do it.